# App Engine Java Error: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: CHARSET_UTF8

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

My App Engine, Java, GWT application keeps throwing the following error only in the production environment (not locally).

The problem seems to be neither caused by the specific code I wrote (we rolled back the code), nor is it the datastore (we tried it with an empty one). We replaced some relevant jar files (like requestfactory-api.jar).
The problem keeps me puzzled...

Is there anyway to dig deeper, to find the point of failure?

```
javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: CHARSET_UTF8
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.SerializabilityUtil.generateSerializationSignature(SerializabilityUtil.java:862)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.SerializabilityUtil.getSerializationSignature(SerializabilityUtil.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.SerializabilityUtil.encodeSerializedInstanceReference(SerializabilityUtil.java:217)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.getObjectTypeSignature(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:651)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:123)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:153)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:585)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponse(RPC.java:605)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForSuccess(RPC.java:471)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:563)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsFilter.doFilter(AppstatsFilter.java:141)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:102)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:447)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

The .classpath file looks as following:  we first try now to update all dependencies, then remove specific libraries to tackle the error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="test"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path=".apt_generated">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.GWT_CONTAINER/GWT"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.GAE_CONTAINER/App Engine"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.google.gdt.eclipse.managedapis.MANAGED_API_CONTAINER/urlshortener-v1r7lv1.12.0-beta"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.JUNIT_CONTAINER/4"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/objectify-2.2.3.jar" sourcepath="/Users/manuel/Documents/workspace/objectify-2.2.3/src">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/Users/manuel/Documents/workspace/objectify-2.2.3/javadoc/"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/gwt-dnd-3.1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/gwtupload-gae-0.6.4-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/gwtupload-0.6.4-20110712.073705-11.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/gwt-servlet-deps-1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/gwt-maps-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/gwt-urlshortener-v1-0.3-alpha.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="war/WEB-INF/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which GWT version are you using? A missing field error seems to suggest that part of your classes are loaded from one version of GWT, while part are from another.

A quick look at GWT 2.4.0 and 2.5.0 point out that SerializabilityUtil.generateSerializationSignature(SerializabilityUtil.java:862) only exists in GWT 2.5.0, and that this field is in com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPCServletUtils. In contrast, 2.4.0 doesn't have enough lines in SerializabilityUtil, and has its own field to deal with encoding. If you have a mix of 2.4.0 and 2.5.0 on your classpath, it could well cause issues like this.

Comment: wow, thank you, that was insightfull. We cleaned up our .jar files, reduced it to what was necessary, updated the rest - and now it works.